# only mange 77% on codility sample test

Tags: java, performance

I tried the codility demo test, but never get more than 77% due to their performance tests.

the test mainly states:
given an array A of N integers, returns the smallest positive integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in A.

Whats wrong with my solution?

The failed performance test comlains:TIMEOUT ERROR
running time: 0.152 sec., time limit: 0.100 sec.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Solution3 {
    int solution(int[] A) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(A).boxed().distinct().sorted()
                .filter(i -> i > 0)
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

        Integer prev_item = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Integer item = list.get(i);

            if (!(item - 1 == prev_item)) {
                return prev_item + 1;
            }
            prev_item = item;
        }
        return prev_item + 1;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution3 solution3 = new Solution3();
        int[] A = new int[6];
        A[0] = 1;
        A[1] = 2;
        A[2] = 3;
        A[3] = 8;
        A[4] = 8;
        A[5] = 11;

        int solution = solution3.solution(A);
        System.out.println("solution: " + solution);
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not appropriate for open-ended questions like this. You can try [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution and it scored 100%. It is in python, if someone wants it in java I will post that too. Just let me know.

```
def solution(A):
    A.sort()
    smallest = 1
    for i in range(0, len(A)):
        if A[i] > 0:
            if smallest < A[i]:
                return smallest
            elif smallest == A[i]:
                smallest = smallest + 1
    return smallest
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that and how you transform the array to an `ArrayList` and put work into cleaning it from negative values.

It would be a lot better in terms of performance if you would just sort the array with `Arrays.sort(A)` and then binary search it for the first positive value and do the rest from there.

Comment: Arrays.binarySearch does not offer "first positive" so you have to implement that yourself

Comment: but the entire task needs to be finished in 30 mins

Comment: I wouldn't say that it is particularely hard to implement binary search in a few minutes.
You just have to keep track of the interval and continuosly divide it like this:
`int min = 0, max = A.length-1; while(min != max) {int middle = (min+max)/2; if(A[middle] < 0) min = middle+1; else max = middle;}` And afterwards `min` would be the index of the first non-zero element. (Took me about 5 mins.)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with following code:

```
function smallest(A) {
  const set = new Set(A);
  let i=1;
  while(set.includes(i)) {
   i++;
  }
 return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how could I know that brute force iteration is a solution here. would expect that performance is bad for big arrays

```
public class Foo {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Integer[] ints = { 11, 2, 6, 3, 4, 8, 1, 5 };
    System.out.println(findSmallest(ints));
}

private static Integer findSmallest(Integer[] ints){
    List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(ints);

    for (int i = 1; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
        if (!integers.contains(i)) {
           return i;
        }
    }
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
}
```